# Создание модели почтового сервиса

Tags: c#, smtp, email, pop3

Доброго времени суток, состоит задача в том, что бы создать модель почтового сервиса, программа должна иметь следуйщий функционал:
Наполнение почтового сервиса пользователями
Отправка сообщений
Сортировка сообщений за розмером
Поиск пользователей которые не отправляли ни одного сообщения.
Прошу посоветовать как реализовать данный функционал, никаких готовых решений не прошу, просто буду благодарен если в комментариях выложите ссылку или напишите какие библиотеки использовать.
Использовать ли SMTP, POP3?

Comment: Под сервисом следует понимать вебсайт типа яндекс.почта?

Comment: Ни чего не понял, вам нужна имитация (модель) сервиса или клиент для управления существующим сервисом?

Comment: Мне нужно написать программу windows forms c#, для реализации этих условий. С чего мне начать ?

Comment: Если это ТЗ, которое вам выдали, то уточняйте подробности у автора задания. Еще раз повторю, из текста вопроса (задания?) не понятно, что именно нужно реализовать, поэтому и посоветовать в общем-то нечего. SMTP и POP это транспортные протоколы для общения с другими почтовыми серверами и загрузки почты на клиент, не думаю, что они вам так уж сильно понадобятся для простой имитационной модели почты, если конечно именно это требуется в задании.